# MyAppHiltApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "HiltApp" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I have a problem how to fix `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.bettehomes.MyAppHiltApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.bettehomes.BetteHomesHiltApp" on path: DexPathList`. My package name is "com.example.bettehomes". I tried clean and rebuild.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bettehomes">

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BetteHomes"
        android:name=".BetteHomesHiltApp"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".BetteHomesActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BetteHomes.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/dark_orange" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_performance_logcat_enabled"
            android:value="true" />
    </application>
```

The logcat shows:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.example.bettehomes, PID: 27056
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
> com.example.bettehomes.BetteHomesHiltApp:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.example.bettehomes.BetteHomesHiltApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip
> file
> "/data/app/com.example.bettehomes-KuesyOEkKsRDfOrSY8aeXA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.bettehomes-KuesyOEkKsRDfOrSY8aeXA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
> at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1090)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6140)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:208)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:205)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6991)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:884)

Comment: Do you have a BetteHomesHiltApp class in your app root folder?

Comment: Yes, I have BetteHomesHiltApp in my app root folder.

Comment: Have you added the @HiltAndroidApp annotation to it?

Comment: Yes, I have added the annotation, but I am using annotationProcessor in app build.gradle instead of kapt.

Comment: Are you not using kapt for some reason?

Comment: kapt fails to build.

Comment: Could you please tell the version of `AGP` you are using?

Comment: agp 8.0.0 kotlin 1.8.20 gradle 8.0

Comment: What is the location of MyAppHiltApp and BetteHomesHiltApp?

Comment: Under "com.example.bettehomes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What eventually worked was:
What worked for ClassNotFound in hilt app was: (of course added `kotlin-kapt` plugin id and id `com.google.dagger.hilt.android` in app's build.gradle) using JAVA 18.

```
`implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:${hilt_version}" (2.46)
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:${hilt_version}'`

For android gradle plugin`7.4.2` kotlin `1.8.20` compose `1.4.6`
```

Comment: This solved my problem
as most of answers are very old and not so relevant

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `kapt` to your project by replacing `annotationProcessor` with the following code:

`build.gradle` project level:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}
```

`build.gradle` app level:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}

android {
    ...
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.6' // Install this version if using Compose
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

This solution is for `AGP 8.0.0`, `Kotlin 1.8.20` and `Gradle 8.0` you are using. I have verified that this works in a new project with the specified versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin fails with error:daemon compilation failed:Couldn't connect to Kotlin compile daemon.

Comment: Can you try removing the  `tasks.withType` block and changing `compileOptions` and `kotlinOptions` to `JDK 17`?

Comment: Umm...I used JAVA 18. Otherwise, with annotationProcessor it compiles and installs app on device. But kapt keeps on failing with couldn't connect to kotlin compile daemon.

Comment: if you are using `JDK 18` and not `1.8` then just remove `tasks.withType` as it forces `JDK 1.8` for `kapt`

Comment: Or you can try `tasks.withType` with `jvmTarget="18"`