# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application class z

Tags: android, kotlin, classnotfoundexception

I'm developing an Android app using Hilt for dependency injection, but when I run the app, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for my `MainApp` class. Here's the logcat error message:

> Process: com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr, PID: 22193
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr.MainApp package com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr.MainApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Yzrf2RBaLzHqDKZsUwqZaA==/com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr-RtyaSVKozlG4L2qYUTxHRA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Yzrf2RBaLzHqDKZsUwqZaA==/com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr-RtyaSVKozlG4L2qYUTxHRA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
> at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1574)
> at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1503)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7558)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2400)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr.MainApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Yzrf2RBaLzHqDKZsUwqZaA==/com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr-RtyaSVKozlG4L2qYUTxHRA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Yzrf2RBaLzHqDKZsUwqZaA==/com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr-RtyaSVKozlG4L2qYUTxHRA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
> at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1232)
> at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1566)
> at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1503) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7558) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067) 
> Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/nat/abudawood_internal_hr/Hilt_MainApp;
> at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
> ... 16 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr.Hilt_MainApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Yzrf2RBaLzHqDKZsUwqZaA==/com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr-RtyaSVKozlG4L2qYUTxHRA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Yzrf2RBaLzHqDKZsUwqZaA==/com.nat.abudawood_internal_hr-RtyaSVKozlG4L2qYUTxHRA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)`

**Code Snippet:**

```kotlin
MainApp
@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApp : Application() {
}

Manifest
<application
    android:name=".MainApp"
    ...
</application>

Gradle Dependencies (app)
    // Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:"2.44")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:"2.44")
    ksp("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")

Gradle Dependencies (project)
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.10-1.0.13" apply false
}
```

I'm using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

**What I've tried:**

- Checked the package name in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
- Cleaned and rebuilt the project in Android Studio.
- Made sure the Hilt setup is correct.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and provide the complete `MainApp` implementation.

Comment: There are no implementations, just empty class

Comment: I feel reasonably confident that there are more lines than the two that you show. I suggest that you edit your question and provide the complete Kotlin file that contains what code you have for `MainApp`.

Comment: It is common to create an empty class that extends the Application class (with hilt), that's done [even in the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#application-class)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MyAppHiltApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "HiltApp" on path: DexPathList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76190626/myapphiltapp-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-hiltapp-on-p)

Comment: that issue was convered multiple times on Stackoverflow, just googling: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path: DexPathList[ "hilt"` will show multiple questions about the exact same issue

Comment: None of them are like my case

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the error.
I changed the Hilt version from `2.44` to `2.48`

```
Gradle (app)
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48"
    ksp "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48"
    ksp 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'

Gradle (project)
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
```